# Ubuntu 18.04, can't enable the mbstring PHP extension

Tags: 18.04, lamp, phpmyadmin, php7

When entering the command

> sudo phpenmod mbstring

it returns error
[image: terminal error]

already tried other solutions available on Google.  Still, no result.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1166730/edit) with including how you do install php mbstring package?

Comment: sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring php7.2-mbstring

Comment: Please don't add **[Solved]** in the title. This isn't a forum but a Q&A site. Since you've already posted what you have done as an answer, please mark that accepted once 48 hours have been passed. For now, I have rolled back your edit. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for the tip and needful action.

Answer (score 1):

- Re-installed mysql-server
- Re-installed php

  ```
  sudo apt-get install php-{bcmath,bz2,intl,gd,mbstring,mysql,zip,fpm} -y
  ```
- Re-installed phpmyadmin

  ```
  sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
  ```
- Restarted Apache2

  ```
  sudo systemctl restart apache2
  ```
- then, executed

  ```
  sudo phpenmod mbstring
  ```

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-php-on-ubuntu-18-04/):

Try:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt install php7.3 php7.3-mbstring
```

Then:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo phpenmod mbstring
php -m
```